# React shows last state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help with my code below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, ListGroup, Button, InputGroup, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FileUpload from './Components/FileUpload'

const MyComponent = () => {

    //dump
    const importData = {

        myFields: ['field1', 'field2','field3','field4'],
        exampleData: {
            field1: "value1",
            field2: "value2",
            field3: "value3",
            field4: "value4"
        },

    }

    const [currentSelectedField, setCurrentSelectedField] = useState();
    const [currentSelectedValue, setCurrentSelectedValue] = useState();
    const [selectedFields, setSelectedFields] = useState({})
    const [currentItemToEdit, setCurrentItemToEdit] = useState()

    const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState('');
    const [editKey, setEditKey] = useState('');

    const alertDilog = (item) => {
        console.log(`You clicked the third ListGroupItem ${item}`);

        console.log(selectedFields[item])

        let exampleData = importData.exampleData
        //  console.log(exampleData)
        let exampleValue = exampleData[item];

        setCurrentSelectedField(item);
        let selectedFieldsObject = selectedFields;
        console.log(selectedFieldsObject)
        selectedFields[item] = item
        console.log(selectedFieldsObject)
        setSelectedFields(selectedFieldsObject)


        //  console.log(importProduct)

        //console.log(item)
        //console.log(exampleValue)
        setCurrentSelectedValue(exampleValue)

    }

    const showExample = (data) => {
        if (currentSelectedField) {
            if (data) {
                return (
                    <span>Example Data = {data} </span>
                )
            }

        }
        else {
            return (
                <span>You didnt select any field
                    <br/>

                </span>
            )
        }
    }

    const checkListData = (item) => {
        let flag = 0;
        Object.keys(selectedFields).map(function (keyName, keyIndex) {
            if (keyName === item) {
                flag = 1;
            }
        })
        if (flag === 0) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    const selectForEditting = (keyName, value) => {
        console.log(keyName)
        setCurrentItemToEdit({ key: keyName, value: value })
        setEditValue(value)
        setEditKey(keyName)
    }

    const selectToDelete = (keyName, value) => {
        let fields = selectedFields;
        delete fields[keyName];
        console.log(fields)
        setSelectedFields(fields);
    }




    const showselectedItems = () => {
       // console.log('render')
      //  console.log(item)
        console.log('existing!')
        if (selectedFields) {
         //   console.log('here')
        //    console.log(item)
            return (
                <ListGroup defaultActiveKey="#link1">
                    {Object.keys(selectedFields).map((keyName, keyIndex)=> 
                        // use keyName to get current key's name
                        // and a[keyName] to get its value
                            <ListGroup.Item key={keyIndex} action>
                                <Container fluid    >
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col xs={8}>key : {keyName} <br /> value : {selectedFields[keyName]}</Col>
                                        <Col xs={2}> <Button size="sm" onClick={() => selectForEditting(keyName, selectedFields[keyName])} variant="outline-primary">Edit</Button></Col>
                                        <Col xs={2}> <Button size="sm" onClick={() => selectToDelete(keyName, selectedFields[keyName])} variant="outline-primary">x</Button></Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </Container>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                    )}
                </ListGroup>
            )

        } else {
            return (
                <span>No selected Fields</span>
            )
        }
    }

    const handleProductEdit = (value) => {
        console.log(value)
        setEditValue(value)
    }


    const saveEditfield = (item) => {
        console.log('save fields')
        console.log(item)
        selectedFields[editKey] = editValue

        let selectedFieldsObject = item;
        Object.keys(selectedFieldsObject).map(function (keyName, keyIndex) {
            // use keyName to get current key's name
            // and a[keyName] to get its value

            if (keyName === editKey) {
                selectedFieldsObject[keyName] = editValue
            }
        })
        console.log(selectedFieldsObject)
        setSelectedFields(selectedFieldsObject)
    }

    const showEditArea = () => {
        // console.log(currentItemToEdit)
        if (currentItemToEdit) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroup.Prepend>
                            <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">Value ({editKey}) </InputGroup.Text>
                        </InputGroup.Prepend>
                        <FormControl
                            placeholder="New value"
                            aria-label="New value"
                            aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                            value={editValue}
                            onChange={e => handleProductEdit(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <Button onClick={() => saveEditfield(selectedFields)} variant="primary">Save</Button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    const showMainArea = () => {
            return (<div>   <Row>
                <Col>
                    {showExample(currentSelectedValue)}
                    <ListGroup defaultActiveKey="#link1">
                        {importData.myFields.map(item => {
                            return (
                                <ListGroup.Item className={'my-1'} key={item} active={checkListData(item)} onClick={() => alertDilog(item)}>
                                    {item}
                                </ListGroup.Item>

                            )
                        })
                        }
                    </ListGroup>
                </Col>



                <Col>Custom Fields
                  {showselectedItems()}

                </Col>
                <Col>Edit Area
                        {showEditArea()}
                </Col>
            </Row>

                <Button variant="success" className={'my-2 mx-1 '}>Send</Button>
            </div>)

    }

    return (
        <Container fluid>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    {JSON.stringify(selectedFields)}
                </Col>
            </Row>
            {showMainArea()}

        </Container>)
}
export default MyComponent;
```

When I click on the "delete" button, I can delete the data from `selectedFields`. But it doesn't show on screen.

For example:

- I clicked value 1
- I deleted value 1
- I can't see empty object on screen, but when I click value 2
  I can see value 2 only on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

When you mutate the state and set it to state, react doesn't re-render your component as it thinks that nothing has changed in your state since the reference is same.

Its recommended that you clone the state before updating it

```
const selectToDelete = (keyName, value) => {
    let fields = {...selectedFields}; // cloning it.
    delete fields[keyName]; // Not update the cloned data
    console.log(fields)
    setSelectedFields(fields); // Now this will trigger a re-render and reflect the change
}
```